# String creation by putting elements inside parentheses

Tags: python

These work for creating a string by defining it's individual elements separately:

```
str1 = ("a" "b")
# str1 = 'ab'

str2 = ("d"+str1)
# str2 = 'dab'

str3 = ("d" "e" "f")
# str3 = 'def'
```

But this one fails. Why so?

```
str3 = ("d"+str1 "e")
# SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What's the work around it?

Answer (score 8):

You're mixing two different things.  `("a" "b")` *looks* like it's two strings, but it's really only one; string literals separated by whitespace are automatically concatenated to a single string. It's *identical* to using `("ab")`.

On the other hand, you can *add* two different strings to make a new single string. That's what's happening with `("d"+str1)`.

The trick in the first example only works with string literals, not with variables or more complicated expressions. So `("d"+str1 "e")` doesn't work. You need `("d"+str1+"e")`, which is two additions.

P.S. the parentheses are optional, they just group together operations that don't need any additional grouping.

Answer (score 3):

Two string literals next to each other are automatically concatenated; **this only works with two literals, not with arbitrary string expressions**:

```
>>> 'str' 'ing'                   #  <-  This is ok
'string'
>>> 'str'.strip() + 'ing'   #  <-  This is ok
'string'
>>> 'str'.strip() 'ing'     #  <-  This is invalid
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
    'str'.strip() 'ing'
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

[The Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings)

More clearer:
[image]

Comment: This is a very vague answer! Also, incorrect. This way of creating strings can work with more than 3 string elements.

Comment: @vishal This is from The Python Tutorial, if you do not satisfy with it, propose a PEP may be a better choice.

Comment: @vishal I think the emphasis is on the fact that both have to be string literals (it can't just be 1 of them is). 3 string literals is actually 2 string literals side-by-side twice.